# Fick's Law over Implicit Regions

Tags: equation-solving, differential-equations

I'm trying to solve 2D Fick's law of diffusion from the boundaries of a triangle (future shapes will include more complex implicit regions). I'm able to model diffusion without time  in complex implicit regions. I'm also able to model diffusion with time over a rectangular region. However, once I use the implicit region function along with time in Fick's law, I get the error message

```
NDSolve::femimvr: The number of independent variables 3 ({x,y,t}) does not match the embedding dimension 2 >>
```

Is there any way to correct my code for this error? I've included the code below.

```
\[CapitalOmega] = ImplicitRegion[(x + y <= 10), {{x, 0, 10}, {y, 0, 10}}];

Dif = 0.0000072;

eq1 = D[u[x, y, t], t] == Dif*(D[u[x, y, t], x, x] + D[u[x, y, t], y, y]) - 1.2;

sol = NDSolve[{eq1, DirichletCondition[u[x, y, t] == 100, x + y == 10], u[x, 0, t] == 100,
      u[0, y, t] == 100, u[x, y, 0] == 100}, u, {x, y} \[Element] \[CapitalOmega], {t, 0, 1000}];

Animate[ContourPlot[u[x, y, t] /. sol, {x, y} \[Element] \[CapitalOmega], 
      PlotRange -> {0, 100}, ClippingStyle -> Automatic, 
      ColorFunction -> "DarkRainbow", PlotLegends -> Automatic], {t, 0, 1000}]
```

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Comment: For future reference, please format your code according to the guidelines in [meta1027](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1027/what-kind-of-input-and-output-code-styles-are-acceptable-in-se). Doing so will encourage more people to consider your question.

Comment: The error message is totally unhelpful, but the problem is that `t` has to come first for some reason. You have to make it `u[t, x, y]` everywhere and do `NDSolve[..., u, {t, 0, 1000}, {x, y} ∈ Ω]`, then it works.

Comment: For now t needs to be in the first position. Future versions all it in the last position as well.

Comment: @Rahul, the fact that the error message is unhelpful, is because it was not intended to fail in the first place; bugs are such an inconvenience ;-)

Answer (score 4):

[*Udpate: simplified `DirichletCondition`, omitted unnecessary `Method` specification.*]

Following the Transient PDE examples in [Finite Element Programming](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/FiniteElementProgramming.html#353016153), I came up with this:

```
Ω = ImplicitRegion[(x + y <= 10), {{x, 0, 10}, {y, 0, 10}}];

Dif = 0.0000072;

eq1 = D[u[t, x, y], t] == Dif*Laplacian[u[t, x, y], {x, y}] - 1.2;

sol = NDSolve[{eq1, DirichletCondition[u[t, x, y] == 100, True], 
   u[0, x, y] == 100}, 
  u, {t, 0, 1000}, {x, y} ∈ Ω]
```

Comment: It should also work without the Method specification.

Comment: @MichaelE2 In fact, based on the observation by @user21, the only substantive difference between your solution and that in the Question seems to be the order of variables in `u[t, x, y]`.  But, why should that matter?

Comment: @bbgodfrey According to the 2nd comment to the question by user21, it seems to be an unintended restriction (bug) that the time variable precede the spatial variables. The error message made me think it might be a space v. time issue, but as I indicated, I sort of stumbled on a working solution by starting with a working example from the docs and adapting it.

Comment: I am not sure the solution is satisfactory though: if I try `ContourPlot[
 u[t, x, y] /. sol[[1]] /. 
  t -> 1000, {x, y} \[Element] \[CapitalOmega]]` I get a very rough function. Or did I miss something?